# RadosGW returns NoSuchBucket error for public URL's when integrated with OpenStack Keystone

Tags: ceph, radosgw

Im trying to integrate ceph RadosGW with OpenStack Keystone. Everything is working as expected, but when I try to reach public buckets with public link generated in Horizon, I get a permanent error ‘NoSuchBucket’. However, this bucket and all it’s content does exists: I can access it as authenticated user in Horizon, I can access it as authenticated user via S3 browser/aws cli, I can see it with radosgw-admin bucket list --bucket . We are running OpenStack Rocky and this issue appears to be with Ceph Octopus 15.2.4 (there was no issues with RGW on Nautilus and Luminous).
Here is my configuration file:

```
<...>
[client.rgw.ceph-hdd-9.rgw0]
host = ceph-hdd-9
keyring = /var/lib/ceph/radosgw/ceph-rgw.ceph-hdd-9.rgw0/keyring
log file = /var/log/ceph/ceph-rgw-ceph-hdd-9.rgw0.log
rgw frontends = beast endpoint=<IP Address>:8080
rgw thread pool size = 512

rgw zone = default

rgw keystone api version = 3
rgw keystone url = https://<keystone url>:13000
rgw keystone accepted roles = admin, _member_, Member, member, creator, swiftoperator
rgw keystone accepted admin roles = admin, _member_
#rgw keystone token cache size = 0
#rgw keystone revocation interval = 0
rgw keystone implicit tenants = true
rgw keystone admin domain = default
rgw keystone admin project = service
rgw keystone admin user = swift
rgw keystone admin password = swift_osp_password
rgw s3 auth use keystone = true
rgw s3 auth order = local, external
rgw user default quota max size = -1
rgw swift account in url = true
rgw dynamic resharding = false
rgw bucket resharding = false
rgw enable usage log = true
rgw usage log tick interval = 30
rgw usage log flush threshold = 1024
rgw usage max shards = 32
rgw usage max user shards = 1
rgw verify ssl = false
```

Any thoughts/help/suggestions/ideas - are very appreciated.

UPD: Here what I found in RadosGW log
For faulty public buckets

For the bucket with public URL (which fails):
2020-08-03T16:26:54.317+0000 7fd4d6c9a700 20 req 115 0s swift:list_bucket rgw::auth::swift::DefaultStrategy: trying rgw::auth::swift::SwiftAnonymousEngine
2020-08-03T16:26:54.317+0000 7fd4d6c9a700 20 req 115 0s swift:list_bucket rgw::auth::swift::SwiftAnonymousEngine granted access
2020-08-03T16:26:54.317+0000 7fd4d6c9a700  2 req 115 0s swift:list_bucket normalizing buckets and tenants
***2020-08-03T16:26:54.317+0000 7fd4d6c9a700 10 s->object= s->bucket=containerA***
2020-08-03T16:26:54.317+0000 7fd4d6c9a700  2 req 115 0s swift:list_bucket init permissions
2020-08-03T16:26:54.317+0000 7fd4d6c9a700 20 get_system_obj_state: rctx=0x7fd59fe3ab18 obj=default.rgw.meta:root:containerA state=0x55bccaea2e20 s->prefetch_data=0
2020-08-03T16:26:54.317+0000 7fd4d6c9a700 10 cache get: name=default.rgw.meta+root+containerA : expiry miss
2020-08-03T16:26:54.318+0000 7fd4d5c98700 10 cache put: name=default.rgw.meta+root+containerA info.flags=0x0
2020-08-03T16:26:54.318+0000 7fd4d5c98700 10 adding default.rgw.meta+root+containerA to cache LRU end
2020-08-03T16:26:54.318+0000 7fd4d5c98700 10 req 115 0.001000010s init_permissions on :[]) failed, ret=-2002

For the same bucket accessing by a keystone user (from Horizon)

2020-08-03T16:24:14.853+0000 7fd4f24d1700 20 req 109 0s swift:list_bucket rgw::auth::keystone::TokenEngine granted access
2020-08-03T16:24:14.853+0000 7fd4f24d1700 20 get_system_obj_state: rctx=0x7fd59fe3b778 obj=default.rgw.meta:users.uid:7c0fddbf5297463e9364ee3aed681077$7c0fddbf5297463e9364ee3aed681077 state=0x55bcca5cc0a0 s->prefetch_data=0
2020-08-03T16:24:14.853+0000 7fd4f24d1700 10 cache get: name=default.rgw.meta+users.uid+7c0fddbf5297463e9364ee3aed681077$7c0fddbf5297463e9364ee3aed681077 : hit (requested=0x6, cached=0x7)
2020-08-03T16:24:14.853+0000 7fd4f24d1700 20 get_system_obj_state: s->obj_tag was set empty
2020-08-03T16:24:14.853+0000 7fd4f24d1700 10 cache get: name=default.rgw.meta+users.uid+7c0fddbf5297463e9364ee3aed681077$7c0fddbf5297463e9364ee3aed681077 : hit (requested=0x1, cached=0x7)
2020-08-03T16:24:14.853+0000 7fd4f24d1700  2 req 109 0s swift:list_bucket normalizing buckets and tenants
***2020-08-03T16:24:14.853+0000 7fd4f24d1700 10 s->object= s->bucket=7c0fddbf5297463e9364ee3aed681077/containerA***
2020-08-03T16:24:14.853+0000 7fd4f24d1700  2 req 109 0s swift:list_bucket init permissions
2020-08-03T16:24:14.853+0000 7fd4f24d1700 20 get_system_obj_state: rctx=0x7fd59fe3ab18 obj=default.rgw.meta:root:7c0fddbf5297463e9364ee3aed681077/containerA state=0x55bcca5cc0a0 s->prefetch_data=0

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue, it was related to a bug that was backported to Octopus v15.2.8 and Nautilus v14.2.12 so make sure to run that or a later version.

Answer (score 0):

V14.2.12 NAUTILUS add negative cache to the system object(https://github.com/ceph/ceph/pull/37460)

then find a bug(https://tracker.ceph.com/issues/48632)

and octopus v15.2.9 fix this(https://github.com/ceph/ceph/pull/38971)

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are trying to say? It is unclear what steps need to be taken...